# Removing duplicate combinations.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have $k=3$ descriptors and for the sake of argument let's label them $-1,0,1$, each assigned to $3$ different pairs of attributes (thus in total $m=6$ attributes), say $(a_1,a_2)$,$(b_1,b_2)$,$(c_1,c_2)$.

This can be viewed as a single vector defining a different case of the model we are studying: $(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2)$.

We wish to "weed out" the symmetric cases, for example the case $(0,1,-1,-1,0,0)$ is symmetric to $(1,0,-1,-1,0,0)$ because values that define the same attribute are interchanged. Similarly, the case $(1,1,-1,0,-1,1)$ is symmetric to $(1,1,0,-1,-1,1)$ and so on..

In total we have $3^6=729$ combinations, but this is significantly overcounting, because the symmetric cases have been counted twice.

How do we go about counting the number of distinct cases in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming pairs of attributes are different, you have to know how many of them are equal in their components i.e., $a_1=a_2$ or any of the other ones. So Let's say $k$ of them are equal, then
$$\sum _{k=0}^3\binom{3}{k}3^k\binom{3}{2}^{3-k}=\sum _{k=0}^3\binom{3}{k}3^k3^{3-k}=(3+3)^3=6^3.$$
The first binomial is choosing which pairs have repeated attributes, second binomial is choosing the different elements of the pair. The last step is binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

For each pair of attributes, a multiset of size $2$ will define the assignment of the descriptors for those attributes without overcounting.

Since there are ${{3+2-1}\choose{2}} = 6$ multisets of size 2 with elements taken from a set of 3 elements (descriptors), and there are three pairs of attributes to assign descriptors, the answer is

$$6^3 = 216$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets for details on multisets.